# How do I have exactly 20 hats?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, winter-bash-2013

I have exactly 20 hats on Stack Overflow:

[image: screenshot]

How does that work? I thought that once you get to 20 The Milliner immediately bumped you up to 21. I seem to have it though, which is weird....

Also, I recall having 19 hats before getting those headphones (yay sekrits, it must have something to do with my recent question), so that should have given me 21 total.

Bug?

Comment: I have exactly 20 hats right now, is Milliner given out on a schedule? I don't like having an inconsistent number of hats!

Comment: Nice brag report. Or, uh, bug report.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The league tables are cached; like the [Users page](https://stackoverflow.com/users) the rank order is cached, and so is the hat count. And like the reputation count, the actual hat list *is not*, so sometimes the information is out of sync.

Your count must've been cached *just before* the Milliner hat was awarded to you.

I count [21 Stack Overflow hats](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/180276/doorknob-of-snow#winter-bash) when looking at your profile, so you *do* have the right number. Just wait a little while and let the cache catch up.

Comment: But I see The Milliner right there on the page...

Comment: @DoorknobofSnow: Yup, I've seen this before on my count too; a hat being pictured but the count being out of sync.

Comment: yep, you're right, it's 21 now. +1; I will accept when I can